# Docusign Going live to another account

Tags: docusignapi

I have a sandbox developer account with an integrator key that has already passed the review process. My client has purchased a production account under his email. How can I upgrade my integrator key to his production account?

Comment: Sounds like a question for docusign support rather than Stack Overflow
https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I actually called tech support and they said "we are only tier 1 that's out of our understanding to email go live or ask a stackoverflow question"

Answer (score 0):

You would need to select Actions drop down in your Integrator Key, On of the option is Go Live, on selecting "Go Live" option, it will open a popup to enter your PROD credential (here your client needs to enter the PROD Admin credentials). For further details, please check https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/api-overview#go-live, it has all the steps to move Integrator Key from Demo to a PROD Account. Just make sure that PopUp blocker is disabled in your browser.

Comment: Appreciate it! The problem was a cookie issue every time I opened that window it would automatically login to the current account so the only option it would give me to promote was my own account. Once I went incognito in chrome it gave me the option to enter the client's PROD login creds.